# how to deal with api key in axios in vuejs 3

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I'm looking for an answer to how to get data from an external API using Axios in vue3, in case of API needs authentication?

```js
import axios from "axios";

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://nutritionix-api.p.rapidapi.com/v1_1/search/cheddar%20cheese',
  params: {fields: 'item_name,item_id,brand_name,nf_calories,nf_total_fat'},
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'API_KEY',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'nutritionix-api.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

The above sample code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an API from RapidAPI, you need to subscribe to it first. I'm assuming you have a RapidAPI account, and you have your unique API key.

I can help and assist you even more effectively you provide what exactly the error is.